# Opening another .py file in a function to pass agruments in Python3.5

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm pretty new to Python and the overall goal of the project I am working on is to setup a SQLite DB that will allow easy entries in the future for non-programmers (this is for a small group of people who are all technically competent). The way I am trying to accomplish this right now is to have people save their new data entry as a .py file through a simple text editor and then open that .py file within the function that enters the values into the DB. So far I have:

```
    def newEntry(material=None, param=None, value=None):
        if param == 'density':
            print('The density of %s is %s' % (material, value))

    import fileinput
    for line in fileinput.input(files=('testEntry.py'))
        process(line)
```

Then I have created with a simple text editor a file called testEntry.py that will hopefully be called by newEntry.py when newEntry is executed in the terminal. The idea here is that some user would just have to put in the function name with the arguments they are inputing within the parentheses. testEntry.py is simply:

```
    # Some description for future users
    newEntry(material='water', param='density', value='1')
```

When I run newEntry.py in my terminal nothing happens. Is there some other way to open and execute a .py file within another that I do not know of? Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: There is but it can be horribly insecure, not to mention a myriad of bugs you'll have to deal with if you instruct 'regular users' to write code. I'd suggest to use some human-friendly structured format like [`YAML`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) which you can easily parse and process with the [`ruamel.yaml`](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module, or you can even use regular [INI files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) and the built-in [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) module. It's easier to teach users a data format than a language.

Comment: I edited my question a bit to reflect this (hopefully its clear), but the idea is that all the user has to do is place the data they want to input within the function newEntry(). It's for a small group and all users are technically competent people

Answer (score 1):

Your solution works, but as a commenter said, it is very insecure and there are better ways.  Presuming your `process(...)` method is just executing some arbitrary Python code, this could be abused to execute system commands, such as deleting files (very bad).

Instead of using a .py file consisting of a series of `newEntry(...)` on each line, have your users produce a CSV file with the appropriate column headers.  I.e.

`material,param,value
water,density,1`

Then parse this csv file to add new entries:

```
with open('entries.csv') as entries:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(entries)
    header = True
    for row in csv_reader:
        if header:  # Skip header
            header = False
            continue
        material = row[0]
        param = row[1]
        value = row[2]
        if param == 'density':
            print('The density of %s is %s' % (material, value))
```

Your users could use Microsoft Excel, Google Sheets, or any other spreadsheet software that can export .csv files to create/edit these files, and you could provide a template to the users with predefined headers.

Comment: I had suggested this and built it out, but the guy in charge of the larger scope of the project likes the newEntry(...) way because then the order of the arguments doesn't matter as much and they are explicitly labeled by the variable they correspond to so there is less chance of mis-allocating values (so says he).